# Saving custom post in custom form

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm tring to save a custom post in a custom form. When I submit the form, all data gets processed, and then I need to save it to the db. I'm trying to do this using `update_post_meta`, but that requires a post id which I don't have at that point. How do I obtain that? Or should I use a different approach for saving the data?

Also, when saving a custom post from wp-admin, I hooked the `save` function to `edit_post`. Because this is a custom form, there is no default hook. I assume that the post itself, without the metadata, gets saved automatically there, so I do I need to reproduce this functionality in the save function of my custom form?

So I actually want to know how to save a custom post (and its meta values) from scratch (without any hooks and post id's).

The code:

```
function dating_user_create_account_validate() {
    $errors = array();

    // Truth verification
    if(!isset($_POST['dating_user_truth_field']))
        $errors[] = "Je moet aangeven dat je de gegevens naar waarheid hebt ingevuld. Vink het selectievakje onderaan het formulier aan.";

    // Empty field validation
    $fields = array('email','gender','sexuality','day','month','year','region','city');
    $unset_fields = array();
    foreach($fields as $field)
        if(!isset($_POST['dating_user_'.$field.'_field']) || $_POST['dating_user_'.$field.'_field'] === '')
            $unset_fields[] = $field;

    function alias($k) {
        $aliases = array(
            'email'     => 'E-mailadres',
            'password'  => 'Wachtwoord',
            'gender'    => 'Geslacht',
            'sexuality' => 'Geaardheid',
            'birthday'  => 'Geboortedatum',
            'region'    => 'Regio',
            'city'      => 'Stad',
        );
        return $aliases[$k]; 
    }
    if(sizeof($unset_fields) > 0) {
        $errors[] = implode(', ', array_map('alias', $unset_fields)) . ' niet ingevuld.';
        return $errors;
    }

    // Email validation
    if(!is_email($_POST['dating_user_email_field']))
        $errors[] = 'Vul a.u.b. een geldig E-mailadres in.';

    // Nonce verification
    $nonces = array('email','gender','sexuality','birthday','region','city');
    foreach($nonces as $nonce) 
        if(!wp_verify_nonce($_POST['dating_user_'.$nonce.'_box_nonce'],'dating_user_'.$nonce.'_box'))
            die($nonce." nonce ongeldig");

    // Duplicate email check
    $mail_args = array( 
           'post_type'      => 'dating_user', 
           'meta_key'       => '_email_meta_value_key', 
           'meta_value'     => $_POST['dating_user_email_field'],
           'posts_per_page' => 10,
    );
    $mail_res = new WP_Query($mail_args);
    if($mail_res->have_posts()) {
        $errors[] = 'Dit E-mailadres is al in gebruik. Kies een andere of vind je wachtwoord terug bij Account > Wachtwoord vergeten.';
        return $errors;
    }

    $password = generateRandomString(15);

    $final_data = array(
        'email'     => sanitize_text_field( $_POST['dating_user_email_field'] ),
        'password'  => wp_hash_password($password),
        'gender'    => $_POST['dating_user_gender_field'],
        'sexuality' => $_POST['dating_user_sexuality_field'],
        'birthday'  => $_POST['dating_user_day_field'].'-'.$_POST['dating_user_month_field'].'-'.$_POST['dating_user_year_field'],
        'region'    => $_POST['dating_user_region_field'],
        'city'      => $_POST['dating_user_city_field'],
    );

    //so I've got no $post_id
    foreach($final_data as $data_key => $data_value)
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_'.$data_key.'_meta_value_key', $data_value);

    send_email($final_data['email'], $password);

    header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'/account-aangemaakt/');
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are doing. Post the relevant code please.

Comment: @s_ha_dum I'm not the best at explaining things, here's some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really an answer but more an explenation to how stuff works.

**What do you mean no post id?

Think about it, you want to 
update a post meta but which post?**

If you are trying to create a new post you need a different code.
if you want to update a specific post you must tell wordpress
which one to update meaning you must attach a post ID.

**[update_post_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_post_meta) function clearly states that the ID is required.**

Since i am pretty sure you actually want to create a new post
from scracth and not update an exisiting post here is an example
how you can do that.

```
$post = array(
    'post_title'    => 'some title',
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'custom_post_name'
);

$new_post_id = wp_insert_post($post, 10, 1);

// Do the wp_insert_post action to insert it
do_action('wp_insert_post', 'wp_insert_post', 10, 1); 
update_post_meta($new_post_id, 'some_meta_field', 'some_data');
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for. And knowing this, the question was a bit iffy...

Comment: Glad this helps mate... ;) good luck